# Force login via Facebook native app from web page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I'm currently using the [Facebook PHP SDK v4.0](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/4.0.0) (so, server-side) but I've been looking at partially using the [Javascript SDK for Web](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.1) if I need to in order to get the login solution I want.

I've looked through the documentation, and I can't seem to find a way to get my webpage to force login via the Facebook native app. Currently it always has the user login via Facebook web page, which a lot of users aren't logged into on their mobile device.

There is an old [open SO question that asks the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933981/login-via-native-facebook-ios-app-from-mobile-webpage), but currently [the only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10934203/761793) there doesn't seem to be a viable solution, as it will do nothing if the user doesn't have the Facebook app installed.

What setting do I need to adjust either with the [Facebook PHP SDK login URL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper/4.0.0) or [Javascript SDK login method](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.1#login) to have FB log in the user via the Native app if they have it, or the web version if they don't?

Comment: It is not possible. There is no way to use the native login if you are a website

Comment: @WizKid I figured as much, just needed a definitive answer from a good source - you count :) If you can please make that an answer on SO, I can mark this as answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's a solution mentioned on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340932/is-it-possible-to-call-native-ios-facebook-login-dialog-from-just-a-web-page-no) using iOS URI schemes & Facebook SSO.